# Dynamic font size Flex 4 to resize when window/panel is resized

Tags: css, apache-flex, fonts, flex4, resize

I have a Flex custom BorderContainer component which has text inside of it. If I were to add this in my main Application inside of a panel, the BorderContainer goes outside of the width bounds of the panel due to the text being a set size. I have all of its components in percentages so that it re-sizes when shrunk, but the one part that contains checkboxes and labels (lots of things with text) mess up since the font size doesn't change.

I am pretty positive that the results I am looking for can be done through embedding the font, though I have not been able to come up with a solution from online. I am trying to do this with a CSS style since I will be using it for many different components (I dont just want to change it in the flex code directly).

**EDIT Solution:**

I attempted to use the ratio as `www0z0k` had suggested but it caused some serious issues when it was re-sized quickly or to a small screen (the component would not re-size correctly because it was multiplying by the ratio. What finally seems to have worked for me and caused no issues was that I ran the code and found the `width` (1152) and `height` (842) of the container.

I then created a const variable of widthX = 1152 and heightY = 842 and in the onResize() function I coded the resize like this:
(where bottomGroup is the `id` of the borderContainer I am trying to resize)

```
bottomGroup.scaleX = width / widthX;;
bottomGroup.scaleY = height / heightY;
```

**END EDIT**

So far I have found some examples of embedding fonts in the `<fx:Style>` and attempted to remove any delaration of fontSize but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    @font-face {
        src: url("fonts\Arial.ttf");
        fontFamily: myFontFamily;
        color: black;
        fontStyle: normal;
        fontWeight: normal;
        advancedAntiAliasing: false;
    }

    s|BorderContainer {
        fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    }   
</fx:Style>
```

If anyone has any suggestions or knows where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: A sample application displaying what my issue is.
**CustomContainer.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Label text="This is a label" />
    <s:Label text="Here is another which add up to take up quite a bit of horizontal space" />
    <s:Label text="Here is another which add up to take up quite a bit of horizontal space" />
    <s:Label text="Here is another which add up to take up quite a bit of horizontal space" />
</s:HGroup>
```

**Main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:local="*"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    @font-face {
        src: url("fonts\Arial.ttf");
        fontFamily: myFontFamily;
        color: black;
        fontStyle: normal;
        fontWeight: normal;
        advancedAntiAliasing: false;
    }

    s|BorderContainer {
        fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    }   
</fx:Style>
<s:Panel title="BorderContainer Component Example"
         width="75%" height="75%" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"> 

    <local:container>

    </local:container>

</s:Panel>
```

I would like to be able to have the font re-size to fit into the panel. I couldn't provide the actual code that I am working on, but this example hopefully gets the idea across.

Comment: What's the question?  And could you post some more code, specifically the code for the panel and BorderContainer you mentioned?

Comment: Uhm, sure, hang on. And the question is are you able to have the text re-size itself to fit into a given area and not go past its border

Comment: New code posted, it is just something quick but hopefully it clarifies the question. I would like the text to re-size to fit into the panel as opposed to just continuing outside of the panel's width.

Comment: Assuming that your Application starts with a width equal to the minWidth value, the reason your BorderContainer is exceeding the width of your Panel is that both the App and the BC have the main width but you set the Panel to have 75% the width of the App.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that on the code I put, but what I actually have it as is the custom container has width="100%" and height="100%" and it is still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be possible to modify font size in a similar way, but imho if you have something except text there (you mentioned checkboxes) you sholud use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%" resize="onResize();">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    private function onResize():void{
        var ratio:Number = width / measuredWidth;
        contentHolder.scaleX *= ratio;
        contentHolder.scaleY *= ratio;
    }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup id="contentHolder">
    <s:Label text="This is a label" />
    <s:Label text="Here is another which add up to take up quite a bit of horizontal space" />
    <s:Label text="Here is another which add up to take up quite a bit of horizontal space" />
    <s:Label text="Here is another which add up to take up quite a bit of horizontal space" />
</s:HGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Main.xml doesn't need to be modified

Answer (score 0):

If you set an explicit width (e.g., 100%) on your Labels in BorderContainer they should automagically do line wraps for you (see: [Label docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html)).

If you want to actually change the font size (and I would avoid this since it will be visually confusing, but that's another discussion) you should be able to change the scaleX and scaleY properties of your Labels such that they will be scaled to fit perfectly in the BorderContainer.  All you'll need to do is compute the scale and apply it.

Comment: The thing is that they are checkboxes and labels (in groups etc) and wraps are not an option (since I have some grids of checkboxes) so I wanted the text to rescale. I will look into the scaleX and scaleY though, I just wondered if there was a way for it to automatically do so or for it to be done in the CSS

Comment: There is no way to do it in CSS that I'm aware of.